# Asp.Net Mvc Selectpicker

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am trying to implement a DropDownList Multi Select using Bootstrap Selectpicker for selecting Schools in my application.

I am not very familiar with MVC and JQuery since i have been using webforms for a long time, so i am learning from internet to accomplish.

Here is the scenario:

on my layout, there is a DropDownList:

```
@*DropDownList Select School*@                                            
@Html.DropDownList("Schools", null, null, new { id = "MultiSelect", @class = "selectpicker form-control", multiple = "", title = "School" })
```

The code to fill the DropDownList:

```
public ActionResult Class()
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListClasses = db.scasy_class
        .OrderBy(a => a.class_name)
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.id.ToString(),
            Text = c.class_name,
            Selected = false
        });
    ViewBag.Class = ListClasses.ToList();

    ClassViewModel classViewModel = new ClassViewModel()
    {
        SelectOptions = ListClasses
    };

    return View(classViewModel);
}
```

On layout, when the user selects some schools, using the dropdownlist,

```
$('#MultiSelect').on('change', function () {
    $.each($("#MultiSelect option"), function () {
        $.post("/Setup/Student/SetSchool/", { school: $(this).val(), selected: $(this).prop('selected') });
    });
});
```

and the controller;

```
public ActionResult SetSchool(int school, bool selected)
{
    ArrayList school_nos = Session["Schools"] as ArrayList;

    if (selected)
    {
        if (!school_nos.Contains(school))
        {
            school_nos.Add(school);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (school_nos.Contains(school))
        {
            school_nos.Remove(school);
        }
    }

    Session["Schools"] = school_nos;

    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

it is working as it is expected until here.
For the next reload, i am trying to fill the dropdownlist with the same data but show previously selected schools with tick, using Session values, since i will need this information on many other pages.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("/Setup/Student/GetSchool/",
        function (data) {                     
            var myData = [];
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                if (item.Selected == true) {
                    myData.push(item.Value);
                }
            });
            //alert(myData);
            $('#MultiSelect').selectpicker('val', myData);                      
        });
});
```

and the controller;

```
public JsonResult GetSchool()
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListSchools = db.scasy_school
        .OrderBy(a => a.name)
        .Select(a => new SelectListItem { Value = a.id.ToString(), Text = a.name});

    ArrayList school_nos = Session["Schools"] as ArrayList;

    List<SelectListItem> ListSchoolsUpdated = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var item in ListSchools)
    {
        SelectListItem selListItem;

        if (school_nos.Contains(item.Value.ToString()))
        {
            selListItem = new SelectListItem() { Value = item.Value.ToString(), Text = item.Text, Selected = true };
        }
        else
        {
            selListItem = new SelectListItem() { Value = item.Value.ToString(), Text = item.Text, Selected = false };
        }

        ListSchoolsUpdated.Add(selListItem);
    }
    return Json(ListSchoolsUpdated, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Code throws no error, but i cannot have the dropdownlist with selected items shown.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a model class for your page

```
public class ClassViewModel {
  public List<int> SelectedSchools {get; set;}
  public List<SelectListItem> Schools {get; set;}
}
```

Set Selected Schools in your controller action.

Set Your View Model

```
@model ClassViewModel
```

Then in your view use this code to show dropdownlist

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(m=> m.SelectedSchools , Model.Schools, new {id = "MultiSelect", @class = "selectpicker form-control", title = "School" })
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments, DropDownList is on the _Layout.cshtml.